# I need help appending the data into a text file

Tags: python, append, text-files

```
Temp = int(input("Temp: "))
Humid = int(input("Humidity: "))
Wind = int(input("Wind: "))
new_data = [Temp, Humid, Wind]
if Temp < 120 and Temp > 0 and Humid < 120 and Humid > 0 and Wind < 120 and Wind > 0:
   with open('C:/Users/amaya/OneDrive/Desktop/CIS 2300/Test_file.txt', 'a') as f:
       new_data.append(f)
       print("ok will append new data")       
else:
    print("The numbers are to high/low.")
    pass
```

Hello, I'm trying to append 'new_data" into the test_file but keep getting this error "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'". I got the same error when I put f.append(new_data). Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `f.write(",".join(new_data))`

Comment: What would I do if i wanted to create a new line after entering the data?

Comment: `f.write(",".join(new_data) + '\n')` also you might want to look into the `csv` module which can make this easier.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome. Happy coding to you!